# Copying email address from to/cc/bcc field only copies name (address not in contacts)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

A salesperson at work asked me to help her copy email addresses from an Outlook bcc field. She sends out emails to various subgroups of her clients, in groups of several hundred. She wants to save the email addresses in Excel.

Edit: to be clear, the workflow she wants is "type in a bunch of emails into outlook, then copy them, then paste them to Excel either before or after the emails are sent"

She will start typing an email and Outlook autocompletes it to the form `John Doe <jdoe@example.com>`

When copying, Outlook only copies the name portion. In Outlook 2010, doing the same thing copies the entire address including the email in brackets.

The address isn't in her contacts (contacts get displayed as just `John Doe`). One solution I've seen is basically "create a contact", but that wouldn't work since she'd have to do it to all however many hundreds of her clients.

The solution suggested [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/pbworks/topics/copy_email_address_from_outlook_and_paste_elsewhere_issue) doesn't work, as the emails are bcc'd and thus wouldn't show up in the email headers.

Comment: Just a thought (I cannot confirm), but is it possible to select the text (name+email), then left-click and drag into the body?

Comment: I am unable to duplicate the issue you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Be on the message and click on three dots on the right(...). From drop down, click "view message source" ( option almost at the bottom). A text will appear.

This text will have sender email and then some longs strings. Scroll a page or two and you will see the email addresses this message was sent to.

Good luck...

RP

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution found on [another forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/how-to-copy-a-list-of-email-contacts-and-paste/aa29e50b-dc8b-42e2-936c-ea8943ec438d?auth=1):

> 1) In the email window, click the `To:` button. The Select Names Global Address List dialog box opens.
>
> 2) Add all of the people you want to any of the fields.
>
> 3) Before clicking OK, copy the names from the desired field.
>
> By copying the names from the To: field in the Select Names window, I am able to get just the names...no addresses...when I paste in the body of the email.

Comment: This does not allow me to copy the text of the email address.

Comment: Wrong answer for the question, but it was what I was looking for, names not email address.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying/pasting the names difrectly from the "to" field in the email, go in the "Address book", paste the names in the "to" field, and when you will copy the names, they won't have their email addresses attached.